# Tabela com width 100% e Scroll

Tags: html, css

Tenho uma tabela, onde ela se ajusta ao conteúdo que possui. Dessa forma, adicionei um `width: 100%`. Ela fica do tamanho da janela.

Dei um overflow-x: auto, assim ela deveria criar um scroll, quando menor. Mas não é isso que acontece, ela só pega o scroll, se eu adicionar `display:block`, mas dessa forma ela perde os `width: 100%`.

Como faço para ter o scroll, mas manter o 100% do width, com `white-space: nowrap;` .

**Ex**: http://jsfiddle.net/CrSpu/9631/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma abaixo, adicionado a tabela dentro de uma `div`:

```css
.my-table {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

table.width {
    width: 100%; /* Optional */
    border-collapse:collapse;
    white-space: nowrap; 
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-table">
  <table class="width">
      <tbody>
          <tr>
              <td>Content 1 olha que legal</td>
              <td>Content 2</td>
              <td>Content 3</td>
              <td>Content 4</td>
              <td>Content 5</td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Ex.: https://jsfiddle.net/YurePereira/kmj7qgk3/

Answer (score 1):

Na realidade a sua tabela tem `width: 100%`, pode comprovar isso acrescentando `border: 1px solid green;` à `table.width {...` e vendo que esta tem os 100%. Ou seja, queremos é que cada td seja redimensionado (aumentado, neste caso cada um fica com 20%, pois são 5 colunas), então é só:

```
td{border: 1px solid #000;width: 100px;width:20%;}
```

Caso queira que o texto não fique colado às margens e fique centrado:

```
td{border: 1px solid #000;width:20%;padding:5px 20px;text-align:center;}
```

[EXEMPLO](http://jsfiddle.net/CrSpu/9637/) no jsfiddle

Comment: A sua resposta também esta certa, mas acabei utilizando a resposta abaixo. ATT

Comment: Ainda bem que resolveu @abcd